# How to define special access characters in typescript declaration files

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have an external API i'm writing type declaration (*.d.ts) files for, thing is one of the interfaces uses "interface.@attribute" to access a subset of it's properties.

Is there a way I can define this in TS? Or if not worst case is there a way I can say that all properties accessed using a string (interface["@attribute"]) that start with an "@" symbol have a certain type?

I'm gathering since this isn't standard behavior this isn't really going to be an implementable thing but I thought i'd ask you guys to make sure. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that as soon as you use bracket notation to access a property (instead of dot notation)–which is necessary in order to access `@attribute`–TS doesn't do any type checking anyway. So you might as well define it as `{[key: string]: any}`.